Can Human Actions Change the Course of History in Hegel's View?
Within the framework of Hegel's historical dialectic, I'm curious about the role of human agency. Can we influence both the direction this process takes and its ultimate outcome? Or is the destination predetermined, with only the path open to alteration?

See Hegel's Lectures on the Philosophy of History: §26 "We assert then that nothing has been accomplished without interest on the part of the actors; and — if interest be called passion [---] we may affirm absolutely that nothing great in the World has been accomplished without passion. Two elements, therefore, enter into the object of our investigation; the first the Idea, the second the complex of human passions; the one the warp, the other the woof of the vast arras-web of Universal History. "

§34 "It is in the light of those common elements which constitute the interest and therefore the passions of individuals, that these historical men are to be regarded. They are great men, because they willed and accomplished something great; not a mere fancy, a mere intention, but that which met the case and fell in with the needs of the age."

Hegel does admit some contingency in human actions, but not in the 'course of history'. "We are concerned with the Spirit’s development, its progression and ascent to an ever higher concept of itself... This universal is an essential phase in the development of the creating Idea, of truth striving and urging toward itself. The historical men, world-historical individuals, are those who grasp just such a higher universal, make it their own purpose, and realize this purpose in accordance with the higher law of the spirit." The role of 'human agency' is to get on with the program.

Hegel's historical dialectic operates within the interplay of freedom and necessity, making the role of human agency a nuanced aspect of his philosophy. To address your question, we must examine Hegel’s conception of history and agency.
Historical Dialectic as a Rational Process: For Hegel, history is the unfolding of Spirit (Geist) through a dialectical process driven by contradictions and their resolution. This process moves toward the realization of freedom, understood as self-awareness and self-determination. While Hegel views this progression as rational and inevitable in its broad outlines, he does not suggest that every detail or moment within history is predetermined.
Human Agency and the Direction of History: Human beings play a crucial role as the agents through which Spirit actualizes itself. Our actions, thoughts, and struggles are the medium for the dialectical process. However, individuals often act out of immediate, subjective motives (e.g., ambition, desire), and it is only retrospectively that these actions are seen as contributing to the broader rational progression of history. This idea is encapsulated in Hegel’s notion of the “cunning of reason,” where reason uses individuals' particular aims to achieve its universal ends.
Influence on Path vs. Destination: While the ultimate destination—freedom and self-realization—is inherent in the nature of Spirit, the specific path history takes is contingent upon human action. In this sense, agency can shape the course, intensity, and character of historical development, though not its final goal. For example, revolutions, wars, and cultural movements are all shaped by human choices, yet they ultimately push the dialectic forward in ways that might not have been consciously intended by the participants.
Freedom and the Ethical Role of Agency: Importantly, Hegel does not see individuals as mere instruments of history. Human agency involves the capacity to understand and align with the rational principles underlying historical development. By participating in ethical life (Sittlichkeit)—through family, civil society, and the state—individuals can contribute meaningfully to the realization of freedom. This participation reflects the synthesis of subjective freedom (personal agency) and objective freedom (universal rationality).

Is this LLM-generated?

Hegel distinguished three kinds of history: a) immediate which is witnessed and executed through ordinary human action. b) Reflexive which is what is written up by historians and c) philosophical which is the subject matter of philosophers of history.
It's only in reflexive and philosophical history that we see the course of history being changed.
Now ordinary human action is both important and necessary to the description of immediate history. This is what is usually transcribed by eye-witnesses, journalists and memoirists. All this is relied upon historians to build a picture of the historical processes - the reflexive history. Here, it's rare to see one person embody the entire history in his actions but it can happen. For example, Hegel wrote about seeing Napoleon ride through Jena, writing:

I saw the Emperor – this soul of the world – go out from the city to survey his reign ; it is a truly wonderful sensation to see such an individual, who, concentrating on one point while seated on a horse, stretches over the world and dominates it.

Thus, this is an extreme example of human actions affecting the course of history. Normally, he would describe this as occuring during the heroic epoch of human history - not our own era. Instead, he ascribed to own era:

“the prosaic character of the present time.”

And he goes on to say:

The monarchs nowadays are not, like the heroes of the mythical age, the physical peak of the Whole, but a center, more or less abstract, of institutions firmly established and protected by laws and constitutions. The monarchs nowadays have let the most important governmental acts escape from their hands. They do not speak the law any more ; the finances, the civil order and public safety are not their special task any more ..."

The monarch's of today are elective monarchs, that is elected representatives of governments.
